# bash getops not passing email or ip address

Tags: bash, getopts

I've been banging my head on this one for a bit. Wanted to see what I'm doing wrong, and it's probably all me on this one. I'm pinging an IP, then when it goes down or up, it will send a notification. My issue is with getops. I'm using it to attempt to parse the email address and the ip. Neither of these are being parsed. How can I go about parsing my two variables using getopts I need to allow my script to run properly. Thank you in advance :)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Variable(s)
# --------
EMAIL_DOWN_SENT="0";
EMAIL_UP_SENT="0";
PING_FAILED="0";
PING_UP_AGAIN="0";

# FUNctions
# ---------
# 
# Echo a string value that is passed
echo_text() {
   echo -e >&2 "$@";
}

echo_help() {
echo_text "Usage: $(basename "$0") [-e] [EMAIL][-h] [-i] [IP]\n\nScript to ping ip address to see if it's up and send an alert on status changes.\n
        -e Enter email: user@domain.tld
        -h This help screen
        -i IP to ping";
   exit;
}

# Main body
# ---------
#
# Get command line options
# ------------------------
while getopts ":e:hi:" OPTIONS 
do
  case $OPTIONS in
     e) EMAIL=$OPTARGS ;;
  h|\?) echo_help ;;
     i) IP= $OPTARGS | grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'; if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then echo_text "Please enter a valid IP"; exit 1; fi; ;;
     *) echo_text "$OPTARGS is invalid, try again";
        exit 1 ;;
  esac
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
done
echo_text "Your email is: $EMAIL";
echo_text "Your ip to ping is: $IP";

# Ping me
# -------
trap "echo You hit ctrl-c, now exiting..; exit" SIGINT
while :
do
   ping -i 2 -c 2 $IP > /dev/null
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      let PING_DOWN+=1
      echo_text "Down! Abandon all hope who enter here...";
      PING_FAILED="1";
      # If greater than 3 cycles send an email...
      if [[ $PING_DOWN -ge 3 && $EMAIL_DOWN_SENT -eq 0 ]]; then
         echo "$IP Down!"|mutt -s "Ping Failed!" $EMAIL;
         EMAIL_DOWN_SENT="1";
      fi
   else
      let PING_UP+=1
      echo_text "Up! Ahoy! Host alive!";
      # If greater than 3 cycles send an email...
      if [[ $PING_UP -ge 3 && $EMAIL_UP_SENT -eq 0 && $PING_FAILED -eq 1 ]]; then
         echo "$IP up!"|mutt -s "Ping succeeded!" $EMAIL;
         EMAIL_UP_SENT="1";
         PING_UP_AGAIN="1";
      fi
      # Reset checks
      if [ $PING_UP_AGAIN -eq 1 ]; then
         PING_FAILED="0";
         PING_UP="0";
         PING_DOWN="0";
         EMAIL_UP_SENT="0";
         EMAIL_DOWN_SENT="0";
      fi
   fi
done
```

---

```
if [ ! `echo "$OPTARG" | grep -qE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'` ]; then
    echo_text "Please enter a valid IP"
    exit 1
fi
IP="$OPTARG"
```

Comment: Parsing, not passing.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the incorrect grammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main things wrong in your script:

First, it's `$OPTARG`, not `$OPTARGS`.

Second,

```
IP= $OPTARGS | grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}';
```

You cannot do that. Change the whole paragraph to something along the lines of

```
if ! echo "$OPTARG" | grep -qE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'; then
    echo_text "Please enter a valid IP"
    exit 1
fi
IP="$OPTARG"
```

It's also worth noting that, unless you are using an ancient `bash`, your shell should have a `=~` operator (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)) that you can replace the external `grep` with:

> When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex3)). The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this partially works.

I had to modify the conditional statement to avoid syntax errors. Now it fails no matter what, If I take out the ! test, it will work, but not actually check the IP $OPTARG. I've added the new conditional syntax to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problems Adrian Frühwirth pointed out, you need to move the shift command to *after* the loop. The way you've written it, it's removing the script's arguments while `getopts` is still parsing them, which will confuse things completely.

```
while getopts ":e:hi:" OPTIONS 
do
    ...
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))  # This must be after the "done"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to enclose $OPTARGS with "" :

e) EMAIL="$OPTARGS" ;;